# sync defects from QC

Tags: hp-quality-center

our QA team use QC to manage defects.
our DEV team use VS2010,TFS2010(for source control only), SharePoint.
the QA team is behind a private network with no connection to DEV network.

what is the best (simple and cheap) way to sync just the defects between the 2 teams?

Comment: It's not 100% clear, are you using sharepoint for defect management ?

Comment: first, thanks a lot.right now at the QA private(closed) network they use QC for defects, at the DEV network we use sharepoint2003 for bugs, but now we move to tfs2010 and we think it's better to use workItems so the bugs at dev network will be on tfs2010. but we still will need to do some disconnect sync method.

Comment: HP ALM Synchronizer will give you exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HP ALM Synchronizer](http://updates.merc-int.com/qualitycenter/qc110/sync/almsynchronizer/index.html) is a tool provided by HP for defect and requirement synchronization between TFS and QC 10 / ALM 11. 
It's free and and relatively simple once you read the manual. You can try and skip manual reading, but I don't recommend it. Both QC and TFS are complicated products, and as such sync between the two is some what complicated as well.

Comment: and what about sync from QC to sharepoint maybe with help from excel file?

Comment: I think this is a whole new questions.
HP ALM Synchronizer supports custom end points / adapters, if you want you can write one for share point. And then sync QC to sharepoint.

Comment: If you only want to export data and not have bidirectional sync, you can go the OTA (Open Test Architecture) route, and write an app that will read defects data from QC and post them to share point via excel or any other type of api share point might have.